# Reserved a room at Days Inn Singapore but my card wasn't charged

Tags: online-resources, bookings, payment-cards

I booked a reservation with Days Inn Singapore using my debit card. It didn't as for the MasterCard secure code, nor I see the money deducted from my account. I would like to know what happens with this reservation, since I see the booking is  valid at the site. Can the hotel charge me without my 4-digit pin or the Mastercard secure code?

Comment: Did you check on the site you booked, some hotels will only charge your card when you use the room or fail to show up.

Comment: You may also want to double-check with the booking site, the hotel, or both, to ensure that your debit card will hold the reservation for you, unless it can also be run as a credit card. And, yes, some merchant systems can run a card without the security code.

Comment: @Dorothy I suspect you are mixing up CCV2 (three digits on the back) with SecureCode. Please see my answer.

Answer (score 3):

MasterCard SecureCode is a brand name for "3-D Secure" (also marketed as Verified By Visa) and these days it doesn't even ask a password [any more](https://blog.siftscience.com/2016/verified-visa-passwords/) which is not surprising because it's one of the worst form of security ever created, here's a paper titled [Verified by Visa and MasterCard SecureCode:
Or, How Not to Design Authentication](http://sec.cs.ucl.ac.uk/users/smurdoch/papers/fc10vbvsecurecode.pdf).

Anyways it's not a requirement for a merchant to use it. In fact, only the card number is a requirement, everything else (even CCV2, the three digits on the back) just decreases the rate for the merchant because there's less fraud. See the answers to this [question](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/21168/how-does-amazon-bill-me-without-the-cvc-cvv-cvv2) on Security SE.